# Trying to scatter objects using geometry nodes but not going as planned

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want something that looks like this:
[image]

but I'm getting something that looks like this:
[image]

I have two questions...

1. Why am I only spawning multiple fabrics instead of the entire flag with the pole? I think I parented the pole to the fabric properly to make the flag object..
2. How do I get the entire flag to show up above the plane?

Comment: If you say that you have parented the fabric to the pole then that would mean that they are two different objects. But in the node tree you are only instancing the fabric. If you want the pole and the fabric together, just put them in a collection and use that collection as an instance. (Don't enable pick instances) I am not entirely sure what your 2nd question means, but If you don't want those things to rotate below a certain angle try decreasing the range.

Comment: Ah, I see! I thought parenting two objects made them one... How do I use a collection in the object info geometry node? I'm not seeing the option to do that in the drop-down https://ibb.co/jR6fr4v

Comment: Use the Collection Info Node and not the Object Info Node

Comment: omg that worked! I didn't know of the collection info node's existence... Thanks for the super fast and clear response!